# Versión NetCore en Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, sdk

Buen día estoy intentado actualizar la versión de NetCore pero por alguna razón Visual Studio no lo reconoce. Alguna idea de por que sucede esto ?

[image: Versiones de NetCore instaladas]

[image: Visual studio]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has actualizado tu Visual Studio?

Comment: Te recomiendo que actualices tu versión de Visual Studio, ya que la versión actual es la 16.7.2

Comment: Basto con actualizar  Visual Studio muchas  gracias